# How do you take two radio button's inputs and output them as an image?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

Here is my code so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/pRXxT/

I am trying to make it so that if I pick a radio box, the image will update with that color, but with two radio boxes instead of one.

Each radio box has a separate part to the filename so that the final result is:

http://blahblah/images/[radiobox1][radiobox2].jpg

I have been playing around all day with this and could use some help. My code is a little messy from trying different things, and I left the code that was able to update only the first image in the CSS section so I wouldn't lose it.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is a mess. Your onclick is calling a function called "BODYColour", yet this function does not exist.

Comment: I would like to help, but I'm pretty confused about what you want. Do you want to combine colors from the selection of two radios into a single color and then colorize some area with CSS and JS? It looks like you're trying to change the source of an image to have a name like "BlackGreen.jpg". Are you really planning to have images for every combination of color selections? Or, would you rather have the combo color generated by JS? Also, as mentioned by #Diodeus, you've got a couple function calls in there with no matching functions.

Comment: Bloody Demon got it. Thanks for helping

Comment: Raymond, you need to mark @BloodyDemon's answer as correct if you expect people to keep helping you!

Answer (score 2):

your code is a little messy it toke me a little while to understand what you wanted and  you have some big mistakes in jquery selectors so here's some corrections and i think this will work:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="radio1" name="BodyColor" value="blk"/> Black<br/>
<input type="radio" class="radio1" name="BodyColor" value="green"/> Green<br/>
<input type="radio" class="radio1" name="BodyColor" value="yellow"/> Yellow<br/>

<input type="radio" class="radio2" name="InsertColor" value="red"/> Red<br/>
<input type="radio" class="radio2" name="InsertColor" value="green"/> Green<br/>
<input type="radio" class="radio2" name="InsertColor" value="yellow"/> Yellow<br/>

<img src="blkblk.jpg" id="FinalImage" height="100px" width="100px">
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var BodyColor = 'blk';
    var InsertColor = 'blk';

    $(".radio1").click(function() {
        BodyColor = $(this).attr('value');
        updateImage();
    });
    $(".radio2").click(function() {
        InsertColor = $(this).attr('value');
        updateImage();
    });

    function updateImage() 
    { 
        //i don't know the uri you actually want so i'm gonna leave it like it is
        $("#FinalImage").attr('src', BodyColor + InsertColor + ".jpg");
    }

});
```

**Edit** just tested and works fine